# How to open the desktop calculator in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8

How can I get to the small, windowed desktop calculator in Windows 8? (specifically Windows 8.1).

In Windows 7 I'd find it in the Start menu, but the "Calculator" icon I found there only opens the massive full-screen version. I find this version really disruptive and distracting, switching in and out of desktop mode to a huge full screen calculator. I much prefer to use the calculator alongside other applications.

---

*This might sound like a trivial question, but when researching it, most of the other results I've found elsewhere on the web have been low quality, vague or needlessly confusing, making it sound harder than it is. We can do better.*

Answer (score 3):

- Type "Calculator" into the start screen search. Two different icons called "Calculator" come up. The **blue** one is for the desktop calculator, which is the same as in Windows 7. Ignore the green one which is the full screen "app" version.
- *(Alternatively, you can also find the blue Calculator icon by swiping down on the start screen, then swiping right. It's under the "Windows Accessories" heading)*
- Left click or normal press to **open the desktop calculator**.
- Right-click or long-press for a menu from where you can

  - **Pin it to the Start screen**
  - **Pin it to the task bar**
  - **Create a desktop shortcut** by choosing "Open file location" which takes you to (for me) `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories`, from where you can right click/drag and create a shortcut

Comment: or `win + r (run)` -> `calc` (which my brain has a habit of autocompleting even when I want something else from the run dialog...)